# How to avoid hard-coding url names in HTML with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Before explaining the question I would like to throw a bit of my HTML code

```
<div ng-repeat="item in employeeNames">
<span>
 <img data-ng-src="http://192.128.1.125/uploads/images/{{item.photoName}}">     
</span>
{{item.name}} 
</div>
```

where `employeeNames` contain array of objects with `name` and `photoName` .

```
$sope.employeeNames=
    [{
       name:Rob,
       photoName:rer343983j38u38r8u3
     },
     {
      name:Alice,
     photoName:dfgrt564yt546y565556r4t
    },
]
```

How  can I avoid hard coding the url `http://192.128.1.125/uploads/images/` in html since I need to change each time when the url gets changed?

Comment: We should always use relative links for internal navigation, and you've just discovered why.

Comment: just fyi, chrome will load dinosaurs data-uris, before angular convert ng-src to src, btw. you need placeholder src on img tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a simple service that serves the `urls`, So if you needs to change urls all you need to do is change this service.

ex:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('URLs', function() {

    var domain = 'http://192.128.1.125/';

    return {
        uploadPath: {
            url: domain+'uploads/images/'
        },

        appImagesPath: {
            url: domain+'uploads/images/app/'
        },

        // for $httpa jax requests,

        getUserDetails: {
            url: domain+'user/details',
            method: 'GET'
        },

        postLoginDetails: {
            url: domain+'user/login',
            method: 'POST'
        }
    }
});
```

in Controller,

```
app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'URLs', function($scope, $http, URLs) {

    $scope.uploadDir = URLs.uploadPath;

    /*
     *--------------------------------------------
     * if you need to process `$http` ajax request.
     *--------------------------------------------
     */
      var httpConfig = {
              method: URLs.getUserDetails.method, 
              url: URLs.getUserDetails.url, 
              data: {}
       };

    // OR 

    /*
     * var httpConfig = URLs.getUserDetails;
     * 
     * httpConfig['data'] = {pram1: 'data-value-1', param2: 'data-value-2'};
     */
      $http(httpConfig).
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

          }). error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

          });
}]);
```

in HTML,

```
<img data-ng-src="{{uploadDir+item.photoName}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Angular's [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service and build the link by using given functions like `$location.host()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use a service to provide all configs

```
angular.module('myApp').service('siteSettings', function(){
  return {
    host: 'http://localhost:5000',
    userApi: '/users'
  }
})
```

and then in any place you can just inject `siteSettings` and use it like `siteSettings.host`

Answer (score 0):

My first thought: relatively simple solution. Make config for your url. Then you simply inject the config in your controller/link. This can be done with the provide... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide

Example:

```
(function () {
angular.module("myApp", [])
.config(["$provide",
function ($provide) {
    $provide.value("siteConfig", {
        imgAssetServerUrl: "http://127.0.0.1/img"
    });
}]);
})();
```

My second thought: use relative url.